# Flexbox: How to get flex-grow working inside an existing flex-grow container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can anyone help with a flexbox inside flexbox auto-grow issue?

I have a layout with a fixed header and footer and an auto-grow content section, using flexbox. Inside the auto-grow section, I have a div that I need to be full-height. Can't seem to get this to work..

CodePen: https://codepen.io/thefootonline/pen/jOXPLzq?editors=1100

```
<div class="app-container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <main class="main-content bg-light">
        <div class="test">Foo</div>
    </main>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

```
.app-container {
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    min-height     : 100vh;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.header {
    position : fixed;
    top      : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    z-index  : 1000;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30px;
}

.footer {
    position : fixed;
    bottom   : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    z-index  : 1000;
    background-color: red;
    height: 15px;
}

.main-content {
    margin-top    : 20px; 
    margin-bottom : 40px; 
    overflow      : auto;
    flex-grow     : 1;
}

.test {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, don't use `<div ... />` in HTML. The header element in your codepen did _not_ get closed there, but your header _contains_ main-content and footer now.

Comment: Second - your `.main-content` is already growing - but since it is not a flex container itself, the `.test` inside it does not also grow. (It will still not have exactly the right height then, but that is due to your fixed positioned header,

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I've updated and closed the header/footer element tags. I hear you re <div> - this is simply a mock up to solve this issue - the real implementation involves vue components.

Comment: @CBroe - making the test element "display: flex;" indeed solved the issue. Thanks. Do you want to submit the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.main-content` is already growing - but since it is not a flex container itself, the `.test` inside it does not also grow. It has `flex-grow` set, but that is not supposed to apply, if the element is not a flex item.

So add `display: flex` for `.main-content`, then its children will become flex items, and properties like `flex-grow` are allowed to apply to them.